# Value of loginError takes time to update in ts file

Tags: angular

When i enter wrong email and password and click on submit then `this.LoginError` in component ts file should return `true` in the console but it returns `false` initially and after clicking on `submit` two to three times only then the value updates to `true`.

[image]

I have commented the line  `// console.log(this.loginErr)` in the services file, now uncommenting `console.log` in that file actually prints the correct value instantly, still I dont know why it doesn't update the value in component ts file instantly. So in the html fine using Login Error only shows after clicking on the button 2 times.

```
onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
  const user = {
    email: this.loginForm.controls.email.value,
    password: this.loginForm.controls.password.value,
  };
  this.auth.loginUser(user);
  this.auth.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe((val) => {
    // this.loggedIn = val.valueOf();
    this.loggedIn = val;
    // console.log(this.loggedIn);
    this.route.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  });
  this.loginError = this.auth.loginErr;
  console.log(this.loginError);
}
```

Services file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  checkStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isUserLoggedIn = this.checkStatus.asObservable();
  loginErr: boolean=false;
  readonly loginUrl= 'http://****************';

   checkLogin() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if(token) {
      this.checkStatus.next(true);
    } else {
      this.checkStatus.next(false);
    }
  }

  loginUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, user)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.success.token);
        // localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(success.success.token));
        this.checkLogin();     
    },
    (err) => {
      if(err.error.error){ this.loginErr = true; 
      // console.log(this.loginErr) 
    }
    }); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected. Just notice the following two lines in your service.

```
checkStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
isUserLoggedIn = this.checkStatus.asObservable();
```

You're initializing your `checkStatus` `BehaviorSubject` with false. And then exposing it `asObservable` via the `isUserLoggedIn` property and that's what you're subscribing to in your Component.

So for the initial time the next callback inside your `subscribe` runs, it would receive false.

Now as soon as you push a new value to the `checkStatus` `BehaviorSubject` by calling `next` method on it, this value will then get pushed down the `isUserLoggedIn` `Observable` stream. And that's when your Component will receive the updated value.

This lag is happening because of `this.http.post(this.loginUrl, user)` call in your service, which will make an async network call and the `subscribe` block on it will be executed by the browser once the call stack is empty. That's how async code works in the browser.

Comment: it doesn't wait for the response and prints false https://i.imgur.com/brisAc9.png

Comment: That's right. It wouldn't stop. That's because you've used a `BehaviorSubject` and you've initialized it with `false`. If you don't want this behavior, you'll have to use `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: Still the subject would still assign it with the value of undefined since we don't initialize any value in Subject

Comment: No, it won't. It doesn't fire until `next` is called on it.